# Can not open project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have visual studio 2015 update 1 .I download the MVC project which is done in .net core. but i can't open the project . it give s following error.
[image]

Another one is this

C:\Users\Anushka\Source\Repos\GuestManagement\GuestManagement\src\GuestManagement\GuestManagement.xproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Users\Anushka\Source\Repos\GuestManagement\GuestManagement\src\GuestManagement\GuestManagement.xproj

How can i reload this?

Comment: Googling for the error message yields this: http://richardleeman.blogspot.co.at/2017/02/cprogram-files-x86msbuildmicrosoftvisua.html. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running VS2015 with update 3 in order to open .Net Core 1.0/project.json solutions. If the project is .Net Core 1.0 or 1.0.1 with csproj then you must have VS2017.

In your case your running a project.json solution, so update to version 3.